# applicationWillEnterForeground is getting hit when user navigate from other app

Tags: swift

I am using the following logic to check if user's token is expired when user is coming from background to foreground which is great and work like a charm!

However, there is scenario when user is already on the foreground and clicks on Login Button, it takes user to third party app (Microsoft Authenticator app) and validate user credentials and then it comes back to my app and hit this logic again which is not desired. I wonder how to skip the following logic if user coming from third party app.

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // the transition from the background to the active state
   guard !isTokenExpired() else {
      navigateToLoginViewController()
      return
   }
}
```

Comment: “and hit this logic again which is not desired” Then the logic is wrong, or is in the wrong place. You need to rethink where you’ve put it. This method runs any time you were in the background and come to the foreground, which is exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this method then you can set a global boolean variable and set it to true when you hit this method and send user to third party app for the first time and then the second time when this method is hit if the variable equals true set it to false and exit method.